# Cucumber/Rspec: Is there a way to extract tests from existing code?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, rspec, cucumber, integration-testing

I'm going to begin learning cucumber/rspec.

I've few application in rails3/mysql and rails3/mongoid which I wrote without any test :-(

Should be wonder if I could have a "cucumber/rspec" generator which could extract scenario and "step definition" for cucumber, just like behaviors for rspec. A kind of reverse engineering code generator, which extract tests from existing controllers/models/views.

Do you suggest any other approach  for having old buggy code alligned  to the future well practice testing ?

I know this completely broke the vantage of outside/in BDD development but, how to sanitize thousand of lines of old code ?

Thanks in advance
Luca G. Soave

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If tests could be auto-generated, we wouldn't need them in the first place, would we?

Here's how to deal with untested legacy application when your time is limited:

- Write Cucumber scenarios for the 3 most important stories in your application. E.g. if you're application is a shopping system this would be: browse articles, add item to cart, checkout.
- When you're adding new features, do it test-driven.
- When you're changing untested code, add a test for the code you're touching.
- When you're fixing a bug, add a test for the code you're fixing.

After a while you will have nice enough test coverage for your application.

Good luck.

Comment: This. I particularly like the advice to just cover the 3 most important stories; anchor the things you value first before doing anything else!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I like your approach and that's what I'm going to follow too. Bye Luca